# Renovate prevent query for local dependencies in maven

Tags: maven, renovate

I have maven multi module project.

Parent pom.xml:

```xml
<groupId>com.group</groupId>
<artifactId>product-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Child pom.xml:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>product</artifactId>
```

When I run Renovate I see in log that `product-parent` dependency is queried to maven central. But I want Renovate to ignore local (in project) dependencies - in other words, **ignore dependencies when dependency have filled in `relativePath`**.

This behavior has other side effects such as when release version of local dependency exists, Renovate prioritize it over `SNAPSHOT` (unstable) and creates merge/pull request on this `product-parent` dependency which is for local dependencies unwanted behavior.

Tested with self hosted renovate v37.173

As workaround I list all affected local parent poms in `ignoreDeps`

Comment: The relative path shows that you have a parent which is by default referencing to a parent of a multi module... why should it be ignored?

Comment: @khmarbaise I mean ignore it from querying to remote registry or even dependency updates. 

In example which I described, I do not want to let dependency to product-parent being updated. Even if somewhere exists newer or stable version. Versions of modules in one project/repository should be aligned.

Comment: Please show the project structure and is the pom which is addressed by using `relativePath>../pom` part of a multi module build (which is strongly assume) ...

Comment: https://github.com/jakoubektom/stackoverflow-renovate-78006971

Comment: I don't get how you can be in a situation where Renovate finds a newer version of the parent.

Comment: One acceptable scenario which I want resolve is if I have multimodule project with application and result of pipeline is image pushed to docker registry but no artifact pushed to maven registries. In that case I want renovate to ignore local parents as well as do maven - to reduce warnings or extra calls (which can be significant number in larger monorepo and multiple maven datasources). With this feature I would resolve also some less acceptable scenarios.